# Change Multiple Attributes Of Image On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the two attributes of image : src & data-zoom-image, on click of a button.

Just Tell me that What I am Doing Wrong in below JS onclick Code.

The src is changing but data-zoom-image is not working correcly.

```
<div class="">
    <img id="zoom_01" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" />
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('zoom_01').src='http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg';document.getElementById('zoom_01').data-zoom-image='http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg'">
    <img id="zoom_01" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" />
</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('zoom_01').src='http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg';document.getElementById('zoom_01').data-zoom-image='http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg';">
    <img id="zoom_01" src="http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg" />
</button>
```

Comment: You use `more` elements with same `id` and that's a wrong thing.

Comment: ID needs to be unique,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have similar ids which should be unique, you have to use "setAttribute" property to modify the attribute values::

```
document.getElementById('zoom_01').setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg");

document.getElementById('zoom_01').setAttribute("data-zoom-image", "http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg");
```

Comment: Bro, Thanks for that.
But data-zoom-image is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jQuery.

Add different `id` to your buttons and on click of them, call `attr` function of jQuery:

```
<div class="">
    <img class="img_1" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" />
</div>

<button id="zoom_01">
    <img class="img_2" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg" />
</button>

<button id="zoom_02">
    <img class="img_3" src="http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg" />
</button>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$('#zoom_01').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg');

    $(this).find('img').attr('data-zoom-image','http://i.imgur.com/Vl2kjp8b.jpg');
});

$('#zoom_02').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg');

    $(this).find('img').attr('data-zoom-image','http://i.imgur.com/fkR51QDb.jpg');
});
```

And don't use same id's for multiple elements. If you wish to achieve such functionality, use `same class name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I take that you want to toggle between two images?

You only need one button containing one image.

Then you write a function in javascript, that will change the two properties for you.